# (Excel) Data Entry Form inputting data into table

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I have created a data entry form in a sheet and want the inputted information to be extracted and placed into a table on a separate sheet.

The below pictures will give you a better picture of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/LpWAQ]

I understand that I am going to need to link a macro to a button in order to achieve this.

I tried to Google the solution and came across this code which apparently takes the data and inputs it into a table. This is the code;

---

```
Sub copyRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

' define which worksheet to work on, i.e. replace Sheet1 with the name of your sheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry")

' determine the last row with content in column A and add one
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' combine G7 and G8 and copy into column A, next empty row
ws.Range("A" & lRow) = ws.[G7] & " " & ws.[G8]
' copy the other cells into their ranges
ws.Range("C6:F6").Copy ws.Range("B" & lRow)
ws.Range("C7:F7").Copy ws.Range("F" & lRow)
ws.Range("C8:F8").Copy ws.Range("J" & lRow)
ws.Range("C9:F9").Copy ws.Range("N" & lRow)
ws.Range("C10:F10").Copy ws.Range("R" & lRow)
ws.Range("C11:F11").Copy ws.Range("V" & lRow)
ws.Range("C12:F12").Copy ws.Range("Z" & lRow)
ws.Range("G6").Copy ws.Range("AD" & lRow)
ws.[A1].Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Simply edit your post and add the code.

Comment: You will need to adjust your code to your spreadsheet. It's currently basing it's number of rows on your Data Entry sheet, rather than the Test Log sheet...

Comment: you also may want to modify this line slightly to avoid possible error: `lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Suggestion: if it's possible for you, in the the data entry sheet, link all the fields to a contiguous cells line that builds up your record then copy that record at the last line of your data table.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't coded in VBA before, then do the following:

1) Fill all the fields in your form with some realistic data.

2) Start recording a macro.

3) Insert a new row to your table (right click -> Insert -> Table Rows Above).

4) Copy the first cell in your form (Asset Tag).

5) Click the relevant output cell in the output sheet (`C5` in Test Log).

6) Paste value into the cell.

7) Repeat steps 4-6 until you are done with all the form fields.

8) Stop recording the macro.

9) Right click the button and assign your macro to it.

10) Test, fix and retry.

By doing this you use the macro recording engine in VBA, which is a great way to start using VBA without much knowledge of it. You want to add the row to the table so that the fixed references that the macro creates (e.g. `Test Log'!$C$5`) always refer to an empty cell.

Unfortunately, the macro recorder will record everything as you do it so you will often want to go into the code and change this and that for it to work. But that's actually a great way to start using VBA.

Your second project will then be to record a new macro when you clear the form and assign that to a different button.

Comment: Now that you have added your code. Just do step 9) in the above!

Comment: I tried this step by step process as it seems logical and should work. I have run the code and been thrown an error with the beginning part of the code when we are adding a new line to the table.

This is the line that is causing trouble;

Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True

Comment: Also, the error message says the following;
Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: I have resolved that issue. It was looking to add a row to the table in the wrong sheet so I had to add;   Sheets("Test Log").Select

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of automation. It's always a bit of a hit and miss in the beginning but once you get going, it should help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim cellArr As Variant, valueArr(0 To 9) As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry")      'this is your Data Entry sheet
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test Log")       'this is your Test Log sheet
    cellArr = Array("E8", "C11", "J8", "C20", "C17", "C14", "C23", "C26", "C29", "C32") 'store the cell address in an array

    With srcSht     'get the corresponding cell values from Data Entry sheet using cellArr
        For i = LBound(cellArr) To UBound(cellArr)
            valueArr(i) = .Range(cellArr(i))
        Next i
    End With

    With destSht    'add data as a row at bottom of Test Log sheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        '.Range("C" & lastRow).Resize(1, UBound(valueArr) + 1).Value = valueArr
        .Range("C" & lastRow & ":L" & lastRow).Value = valueArr
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```